# Making a query on 2 columns as if they were one

Tags: mysql, sql, database

There are 2 columns containing the same kind of data:

```
col_a  col_b ...
Bob    Tim   ..
John   Frank .
Bob    John
John   Tim
Bob    Bob
Frank  John
```

Now the query I want to do is like this (counting occurrences: (Bob, 3), (John,2), .. ):

```
SELECT col_a, count(*) AS total FROM table1 GROUP BY col_a
```

But instead of running it on col_a I want to run it on col_a and col_b at the same time ((Bob,4), (John, 4), ..)

Any help is appreciated

edit:
    THANKS EVERYONE YOU ARE AWESOME.

Thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Select Z.name, Count(*) As Total
From    (
        Select col_a As name
        From total
        Union All
        Select col_b
        From total
        ) As Z
Group By Z.name
```

Comment: quick answer! Z as an alias though? >.< makes my head hurt!

Comment: @N8 - "Z" is arbitrary. Could use any alias you like as long as you use an alias.

Answer (score 4):

```
select Name, count(*) as Total
from (
    select col_a as Name from MyTable
    union all
    select col_b from MyTable
) a
group by Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your `Bob Bob` column, I'd think you need to group on subqueries:

```
select idx, sum(count)
from (
    select col_a as idx, count(*) as count
    from table
    union all
    select col_b as idx, count(*) as count
    where col_a <> col_b -- avoid dups
    ) as counts
group by idx
```

or:

```
select idx, count(*)
from (
    select col_a as idx
    from table
    union all
    select col_b as idx
    where col_a <> col_b -- avoid dups
    ) as counts
group by idx
```